# Rails error : undefined method `product' for #<User:0x00007faaa8c42700> Did you mean? products products=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, associations, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to develop a `Shopping application` which has 3 models namely `User(Devise)`, `Product` and `Batch`. I've made an `has_many` association between `User` and `Product` and created a `User(signed up in Devise)`. And then I changed the association into `has_and_belongs_to_many` and created a migration to create the join table. I've followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017241/9110386 to add the `Product` to `current_user`.  Then I deleted my User account and tried to sign up but it shows an error like this.
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `product' for # Did you mean? products products=

**User model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates_length_of :product, maximum: 10
end
```

**Product model:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :batch
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_associated :user

end
```

**Product Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
  end

  def update 
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def add_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    #current_user.products << product
    #current_user.products << product unless current_user.products.include?(product)
    if current_user.products.include?(product)
      redirect_to products_path, notice: "Already in your cart"
    else
      current_user.products << product
      redirect_to products_path, notice: "Added to cart"
    end
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong here. And I also want to remove the `Product` from the cart by destroying it from the `current_user`. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you modify the default Devise::RegistrationsController?

Comment: It seems that the error raised in this line: `validates_length_of :product, maximum: 10` in user model, does users table model have column called `product`?

Comment: @ricks There is no controller for Devise. How can I modify the default Devise:: RegistrationController?

Comment: @ricks Can you please explain how to modify the controller since I can't find any controllers for Devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left behind an old validation in your user model.

Delete this line in the app/models/user.rb file
`validates_length_of :product, maximum: 10`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I want to remove the **Product** from the **current_user** like I added a **Product** to **current_user** by **add_cart**. How to do that?

Comment: @PranavRk You need to make new questions if you want to ask about different topics, this is done to ensure everyone stays on top for the specific question asked. Please create a new question with more details about what you need

Answer (score 1):

Your error is flagging the Devise RegistrationsController’s create method. You’ve likely left a reference to user.product in there whereas users have products plural.

Comment: Thanks but how can I do that and there is no controllers called Devise RegistrationController. Do I have to create controllers for Devise by myself?

Comment: Ok. It’s probably not in there then. Can you post the full stacktrace leading up to `NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create undefined method `product' for # Did you mean? products products=`

Comment: Devise has a rake task which will create the devise controllers for you. But you only need these if you want to customise the login or sign up flow. If you’ve not done this; my answer is wrong.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't create the devise controllers. Why is it throwing this error?